# Can I use Pollard'-Rho even when the order is not a Prime?

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm

I am now solving the ECDL problem.

I want to use [discrete_log_rho] in SageMath, but I can not use it because ORDER is not a prime number.

Can I change it to a decimal number close to ORDER at my disposal?

I tried to use another method, but the size of F was 100bit, so I could not use BSGS because of memory problem.

If I can not use Pollard's-Rho and BSGS, what else is there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the order is not prime, you first use Pohlig-Hellman to reduce it to several instances where the order is prime, and use rho to solve those.